# How to check if a variable has increased (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement

I want my code to check if a variable has increased. For example, I have a function that looks for the letter A in a text box, which runs every time a key is pressed. Then it counts the number of A's it has found. Then I want to alert me everytime a new A is written. I thought I could do this easily by just checking if the var numberOfA has increased in an if statement, and if it has to alert me, but I can't figure it out. I have tried using ++ and =/== in my if statement, but it alerts me every single time a letter is typed, instead of only everytime an A has been typed. All help is appreciated, I'm pretty new at this.

```
function checkForA(){
var sentence = document.getElementById("userText").value.match(/a/g);
var numberOfA = sentence.length;

if (numberOfA = numberOfA +1) {
 alert(" The letter A has been typed ");
 } 
}
```

Comment: didn't get you here, please it alerts me every single time a letter is typed, instead of only everytime an A has been typed.  what do you want

Answer (score 0):

Several problems.

When you write `numberOfA = numberOfA + 1`, you actually assign a value to `numberOfA`. Use `a === b` if you want to test equality.

Also, if you decide to use `numberOfA` to store the previous count, then you need to compare that with the current `sentence.length` value.

As a side note: if you are new, then invest time in learning how to use the debugger (e.g. in the browser dev tools). It will save you a lot of time and help you really understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can not check numberOfA = numberOfA + 1 in your if statement. You can try this -

```
var numberOfA = 0;
function checkForA(){
    var sentence = document.getElementById("userText").value.match(/a/g);
    if (sentence.length > numberOfA) {
        numberOfA = sentence.length;
        alert("The letter A has been typed. In your sentence A has found "+numberOfA+" times.");
    } 
}
```